# How to prevent remote debugging of android webview

Tags: android, webview

I have an ebook app, and I want to prevent someone from modifying my app apk to enable webview debugging and copy the book content by setting setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled to true. My question is how to detect if the android webview is being debugged remotely and then I will not render the book content. Thank you.

Comment: If an attacker can modify your APK to enable remote debugging, he will also be able to remove the check if the webview is debuggable. In my opinion for displaying protected media a WebView is simply the wrong choice. And for hardening an APK you need a commercial obfuscator & protector tool.